# Set permissions for gs bucket object for speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api, gsutil

I want to transcribe a long audio file to text.

So I created a bucket and set it as private using

`gsutil acl set private gs://bucket`

then I set the upload only access from a particular account

`gsutil acl ch -u myaccount@provider.com:WRITE gs://bucket`

then I set the read permission to service account to bucket

`gsutil acl ch -u projectname@projectname-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com:R gs://bucket/`

then I sent a request using a python program but it returns `403` but if I set the object as public then it returns `200` But I don't want to set the permission as public for files .

Is there anything else I can do ?

Is it compulsory to make the audio file as publicly accessible for text generation?

I followed this to set service account permissions :https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638730/4320263

Comment: Where is your python program running on? Your local machine? An app Engine app? And is it trying to write to the bucket?

Comment: @LundinCast Python program is running on local and I am passing bucket object location as payload.Its just sending the POST request to speech API

Answer (score 1):

Granting a user read permission on a bucket through an ACL [doesn't allow the content within to be downloaded](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions), rather just to list the contents.
You can either set an ACL read permission on the object itself:

```
gsutil acl ch -u projectname@projectname-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com:R gs://bucket/file.xxx
```

or you can grant [Storage Object Viewer IAM policy on the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add) to access the entire bucket's contents.