# Getting 403 from Google Sheets API using apikey

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been using Google Sheets as a simple data backend for some apps of mine. Basically these are 20 rows by 20 columns that a client wanted to be able to easily change. I've been getting the data via a call like this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/myspreadsheetid/values:batchGet?ranges=dynamicdatafromapi&majorDimension=ROWS&key=myapikeyfromgoogle
```

All of a sudden, these calls aren't working right. I'm getting

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
```

Even within google's API explorer I'm seeing warnings about oauth only.

Any idea what might be up? I can't get this to work.

I read these answers before asking:

- [Google Sheets API V4 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009410/google-sheets-api-v4-403-error)
- [Google Sheet API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750946/google-sheet-api-v4)
- [Google Speech API returns 403 PERMISSION_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943432/google-speech-api-returns-403-permission-denied)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51261332/9337071

Comment: For closure, Google has fixed the problem. At least my use of an API key to read data from a spreadsheet shared as "anyone with the link can view" is now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an error on google's side. Lot of people are facing this issue today. hopefully google will clear it soon. Our site is down because of this :(

See related question: [Cannot access public sheet with Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391573/cannot-access-public-sheet-with-sheets-api)